# Modx Revolution restrict access to users

Tags: modx-revolution

Apologies if this is a fairly simple question, yet upon googling around I can't seem to find a simple answer.
I as administrator can do everything, create chunks, snippets, pages etc. Which is fine. What I want to be able to do is define a user that can only update the existing pages and thats all. This should prevent them from destroying the site with illogical pages as has been the case in the past.

Is it possible to create a user who has just this ability?

Thanks in advance.
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options, either create a custom access policy that does not grant 'create' or 'new_document' permissions (you might want to look at restricting all permissions starting 'new_', or put all existing resources in a restricted resource group, and only give them access to that resource group. The latter method is probably more flexible in the long run.

Comment: If you want to use the first option (custom access policy), you can duplicate the existing policy 'ContentEditor' which already grants only very restricted rights and add what you need in addition to this. Since permissions in modX revolution are pretty complex to understand in the beginning, you might read the excellent [tutorial on modx revolution permissions](http://bobsguides.com/revolution-permissions.html) by Bob Ray.